# yii2 exist validator with scenario does not work

Tags: php, yii2

Scenario "withAppId" was defined and rule for "application_id" was linked to one, an ActiveField was added to form, but model doesn't save the field. What I did wrong?

Controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $model = new Option();
    $model->scenario = 'withAppId';
    if ($model->load($post) && $model->save()) {
        Yii::$app->session->addFlash('success', 'Запись успешно сохранена.');
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        //form rendering
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['key', 'trim'],
        ['key', 'required'],
        ['key', 'string', 'max' => 100],

        ['option', 'string', 'max' => 255],

        ['type', 'required'],
        ['type', 'in', 'range' => array_keys(self::$TYPES)],

        ['uploaded', 'image', 
            'extensions'    => 'png, jpg, jpeg, gif',
            'maxWidth'      => 1000,
            'maxHeight'     => 1000,
            'maxSize'       => 1024*1024,
        ],

        ['application_id', 'exist',
            'targetClass' => Application::className(),
            'on'          => ['withAppId'],
        ],
    ];
}

public function scenarios()
{
    $cenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $cenarios['withAppId'] = $cenarios[parent::SCENARIO_DEFAULT];
    return $cenarios;
}
```

When `'on' => ['withAppId'],` is removed the saving works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$cenarios[parent::SCENARIO_DEFAULT]` is empty. Try this:

```
public function scenarios()
{
    return [
        self::SCENARIO_DEFAULT => ['key', 'option', 'type', 'uploaded'],
        'withAppId' => ['key', 'application_id', 'option', 'type', 'uploaded']
    ];
}
```

Or you may write `on` condition in rules. There is part of doc [scenario](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#scenarios()-detail) method:

> The default implementation of this method will return all scenarios found in the [[rules()]] declaration. A special scenario named [[SCENARIO_DEFAULT]] will contain all attributes found in the [[rules()]]. Each scenario will be associated with the attributes that are being validated by the validation rules that apply to the scenario.

Note: if you append parent scenarios like this `$cenarios = parent::scenarios();` then always append parent rules.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works fine. Is there a way to automate the hell like `self::SCENARIO_DEFAULT => ['key', 'option', 'type', 'uploaded'],`? Many models in the project have same scenarios set and their attributes are edited often.

Comment: @Mik I updated my answer. You can write `on` conditions in rules and base `scenarios` method will automate configure scenarios. Or choose something between.. :)